# In Laravel, when to use dependency injector, when to use static method, when to use method, and how to communicate between them in correct way

Tags: php, data-structures, architecture

What I'm about to ask maybe the best practice or good data structure design. I don't know what the correct title to give, please corrected it if I'm wrong..

Example I have data structure like this

App

- Controller (Controller.php)
- DataProcessing (Processing.php)
- - Sub data process (RemoveCrapDp.php)
- Computed (Computed.php)

What is the best method to communicate between each of them?
Currently I'm using

- From controller, I'm passing data to data processing using dependency injector that has been registered as service provider.

```
class Controller
{
  public function index(Request $req, Processing $dp) {
    $dp->method($req->get('some_data'));
  }
}
```

- And data processing method accept the request data and store the data as private var..
- It then process the data to remove some white space, basic processing & etc..

```
class Processing
{
  private string $data;

  public function method(string $data) {
    // Pre-processing

    // **Question 1:** What is the good way to call RemoveCrapDp from this method?
    // [Problem 1] - See below for better understand
    
  }
}
```

**Question 2:**
Since RemoveCrapDp will return back the processed data to Process class..

Where the `Computed` class should be called?

- Should it called from `Processing` class?
- Or should it called from `RemoveCrapDp` class?
  And why?
- And what is the correct way to call this `Computed` class,,, still see [Problem 1] for your better understanding
- Or anyone has a better suggestion rather than the suggested?

**Question 3:**
In the `Computed` class,, since it only perform calculation.. What is the good way to design it?

- Should the method be independent? Or dependent?
- See [Problem 2] for better understanding

**Question 4:**
From this situation, could suggest when and where to use static method or normal method

**Problem 1**

```
class Processing
{
  public function method(string $data, RemoveCrapDp $rc) {
    $rc->setData($data); // data is pass using setData method. Since the class already injected
    $rc->callOtherMethod();
  }
}
```

```
class Processing
{
  public function method(string $data) {
    $result = new RemoveCrapDp ($data); // data is pass to constructor
    $result->callOtherMethod();
  }
}
```

```
class Processing
{
  public function method(string $data) {
    $result = (new RemoveCrapDp())->setData($data); // class method
    $result->callOtherMethod();
  }
}
```

```
class Processing
{
  // I know this method not make sense for this case
  public function method(string $data) {
    RemoveCrapDp::setData($data); // static method
  }
}
```

**Problem 2**

```
class Computed
{
  public static function someMethod1(int $mode) {
    return ($mode == 0) ? true : false
  }

  // Seeing here, `int $mode` is redundant from method1. Should I use a var instead and set it?
  public static function someMethod2(int $mode) { 
    return ...
  }

  // Seeing here, This method call another class method. Should I do that? Or called someMethod1 from other file and get it value.. Then pass it to this method..
  public static function someMethod3(int $mode, int $number) { // Method3
    // Some operation
    return self::someMethod1(mode);
  }

  // I re-duplicate method3 to show, should it call like this rather than using method3?
  public static function someMethod4(bool $method1) { // Method4
    if (method1) {
       return method1;
    }
    return ;
  }
}
```

Example of method2 from above for better understanding

```
  private int $mode;

  public function setMode(int $mode) {
    $this->mode = $mode
  }

  public static function someMethod2() { 
    // Use $this->mode since it has been set using setMode.....
    return ...
  }
```

Comment: This question is too nebulous to give a concise answer to, but I would say you're going down the wrong path when your application has a generic `computed` class. Stick with controllers, models, and service providers until you have a reason to break out. You can develop relatively large applications with just those 3 components. Finally, look into Pipelines for data processing.

Comment: Hi.. `Stick with controllers, models, and service providers until you have a reason to break out`.. I have the reason to break it down. Since the project not using Laravel structure anymore.. This is not a small project.. I have migrate to CQRS, DDD, n-layer and some other design pattern before.. Until I realize, I want to create my own data structure that I'm easily understanding & manage..

Also,, adding that.. For the past few year, After I came out from JS world.. I'm become confused by separation the files followed by Model, Controller & etc..

Comment: But rather prefer to use design pattern as JS offer where I create a User files,, and put all model, controller & etc inside of it.. That's my personal preference.. And I'm having no issue with these code.. Only,,, I want to know how the best way to design it by using the given examples above? I'm just asking for opinion so that I can decide how to structure it.. :).. Regarding to this `Since the project not using Laravel structure anymore` ,, it would give me a great pain if I choose to restructure the code followed by Laravel pattern since the project almost finish..

Comment: `when your application has a generic computed class` ,, Erm.... Actually, I prefer this way since it will follow Vue structure.. Perhaps,, if you ask about why I do that in first place.. Because it's an API only application.. No view files, no css, and there's no UI is placed on this application.. And I hope to follow Vue design pattern even tho I know it break the Laravel law.. But as long I know what I'm doing,, it's ok.. Could you clarify about this `Finally, look into Pipelines for data processing`..

Comment: You need to provide us with concrete examples of the services you want to implement. We can't understand what you're trying to build with examples like `Processing`, `RemoveCrapDp`, and `Computed`. For example, if your application needs to process CSV files, then you could create a CSVFormatter service provider that holds all the logic needed. If that gets too large then break that up into parent/child classes, or some other patten,  but we really can't recommend anything based on the fluff you've given and will be closed shortly.

Comment: Re: Pipelines see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IePEWGF-hY

Comment: I see,, sorry for lacking in information provided.. I also don't know that information is also a requirement.. The service that I build, an API service.. The device that connect to it mostly IoT device such as nodeMCU & the data from MCU is sent straight away to that API.. So it consist too much junks in data.. Also,, The RemoveCrap library is used by multiple type on IoT device such as RPI, MCU, custom device & etc.. So it set of str_replace, preg_match & etc to only get the clean data that I want according to device type.. In RemCrap, there's a logic to determine what type of device & etc

Comment: And,, after data processing where I get the clean data.. I must do computing.. That what i'm mentioning in computing class before sending the computed/correct data back to controller to be placed on DB.. And from front end part is where the data is controlled.. Eg,, In Vue interface.. If I say Iot car to move.. It sent data to laravel.. then Iot device will know what to do after that.. The processing part only be use to clean data from IoT device.. While there's no need for Vue.. But the Vue required the computing library sometimes

Comment: I mean no offense by the word junk or crap.. Even tho,, that's my library name :),,, The name regarding of junk.. How do I know what kind of data coming from.. Because some IoT device not program by me but my colleague.. Ex: I only need the value of 22 (random, cant guess).. But the problem is there is data that `34left 2min ***online 78 #dev32 22 access \t` .. You know what I mean by it right.. This is the example data.. And I must clean it all using some algorithm before could fetch some clean data.. And sometime I need more than 1 data example 22 and dev32

Comment: Came across this video today, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q08X7a5VfhE. It may address some of your questions about static, instance, or DI services.